# Where is KBOS runway 15R's localiser array?

Tags: airport-design, localizer

Of the eight major-runway directions at [KBOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logan_International_Airport), five (4R, 15R, 22L, 27, and 33L) are equipped with ILS (ILS-III for 4R and 33L, ILS-I for the rest).  Four of these (4R, 22L, 27, and 33L) have a localiser array some way past the end of the runway (or, in 4R's case, on the other side of Belle Isle Inlet in line with the runway).

15R, however, has no visually-apparent localiser array (this image, and all others in this question, were made by me screenshotting Google Maps), although the *glideslope* antenna for 33L (15R going the other way) can be seen:

[image: hmm, something's missing here]

Contrast, for example, 22L, where the localiser is immediately obvious:

[image: 22L is localised]

Now, the EMAS bed just past the end of 15R *does* have a bunch of posts sticking up from it (visible mostly via the shadows they cast on the light-grey EMAS blocks); however, these are almost certainly approach lights, given the suspicious similarity of their arrangement to that of the approach lights on the pier beyond:

[image: EMAS posts]
[image: approach lights on EMAS v. approach lights on pier]

So where *is* 15R's localiser?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image]

It's offset. Also hence the higher than typical [Decision Height](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Decision_Altitude/Height_(DA/DH)) (250 ft).

PS The pier is new. In 2006 a B767-capable EMAS was built, and in 2013 as an improvement a larger B747-capable EMAS (EMASMAX) was built on a pier ([runwaysafe.com](https://runwaysafe.com/references/bos-boston-logan-international-airport/)).

[image]

PPS The area where 22L's LOC is located was a lot different in the past too (2002):

[image]

Rwy 32 didn't exist.

Comment: Both the the approach lights on the EMAS and the localizer array are visible on [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmnEJ.jpg) from [this video](https://www.gettyimages.de/detail/video/shot-of-an-aircraft-landing-at-the-logan-stock-videomaterial/1183148809). And antennas also visible [here](http://www.cpsprecast.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/logan-1.jpg). Everything low resolution though.

Comment: The pier I was referring to was actually the long thing with the approach lights on it (present even in the oldest of the four time-slices), not the thing the big EMAS is on.  Still, you answered the question I asked, so I'm not really complaining.  :-P